# Crontab append a command to certain user using shell

Tags: linux, shell, crontab

I am trying to set up a cron job using a shell script but I am unable to find a solution to it I am trying to use crontab like this:

```
#cron.sh
echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab -
```

I can run cron.sh as a sudo user So my question is how to add this cron job to a specific user I am using this command:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c  "echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab -" -g user user
```

but it doesn't work how to make the above code work.

Answer (score 0):

It is your quoting.

```
su -s /bin/bash -c  "echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab -" -g user user
```

The first string is `"echo "`. Then, there is an `*`. Basically, that's a list of the content of your directory. Try `echo *` to find out what that exactly is.

`/1` is just `/1`. The next 4 `*` will again expand to the content of your directory.

Then follows a string `" | crontab -"`. And after that, `-g user user`.

```
su -s /bin/bash -c  'echo "*/1**** /opt/file/test.sh" | crontab - -g user user'
```

would be closer to what you want, probably.